# Github Actions subdirectory as NPM Module

Tags: github, npm, github-actions

Is it possible using Github actions to treat a subdirectory as base to publish NPM Modules?

I.E.

I have a project. In the project there is directory with a library.

The library is generic enough that it can be used as a stand-alone NPM module.

When I push to Github (and there is a diff in that subdirectory), I'd like to push / publish a new version of the library to NPM.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a pipeline by a set of files or directory. So whenever you modify any file or set of files in that directory the pipeline triggers

```
on:
   # Trigger the workflow on push
   push:
     # Match all javascript files withing lib_dir directory
     paths:
     - 'lib_dir/**.js'
```

The above will trigger the pipeline when only the javascript files in directory lib_dir are modified

```
├── lib_dir
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── candy.js -> If modified triggers pipeline
│   └── test.js -> If modified triggers pipeline
```